# Why is the following combinatorial identify true?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I have the following expression, the source of which I am omitting because I dont think it is important.
For whole numbers $n,k_2,k_1\leq n,i_1\leq k_1,i_2\leq k_2, m\leq n$, consider

$$\sum_{i_1=0}^x  {m-i_1 \choose x-i_1} {k_1 \choose i_1} {n-k_1 \choose m-i_1}\sum_{i_2=x-i_1}^x  \frac{ {i_1 \choose i_2 - (x-i_1)}  {k_2 \choose i_2}{n \choose m-i_2}} {{m \choose i_2}}$$

Turns out that the above is *exactly* equal to ${n-k_1 \choose m-x}{k_1+k_2 \choose x}{n \choose m}$ -- see this plot (I scaled both the terms so that the graph is *nice*) - https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zfllweabq8

I am unable to prove why this is true. I get a sense that this looks like [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity), only much more complex. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: does the inner sum starts at $x-i_1$ instead?

Comment: Yes, sorry, Correcting now.